# How to add a html bold <b> in the jsf tags

Tags: jsf

I defined below property in property file.

```
<b>Profile 1:</b> <br> Only the market(s) selected above
```

I set this in bean profile1

```
<h:outputText style="font-size:12px;" value="#{bean.profile1}" />
```

But result is

```
<b>Profile 1:</b> <br> Only the market(s) selected above
```

Can please anybody help how to give break and bold
 in property file?

Answer (score 2):

Use `escape=false` in the `h:outputText`:

```
<h:outputText style="font-size:12px;" value="#{bean.profile1}" escape="false"/>
```

Otherwise all special characters are escaped during jsf processing.

Comment: Thank you Handy. I have given same to select items. Is there any error?                                                  <h:selectOneRadio id="profiles" layout="pageDirection" value="#{bean.selectedProfile}" style="font-size:12px;">
<f:selectItems value="#bean.profiles}" escape="false"/>                          </h:selectOneRadio>